# Alguna forma de hacer esto con Node Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs

saben como puedo hacer este código pero con javascript/Node js para poder manipular estos datos con css y html, que no sea con PHP?

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;

foreach($valor as $v) echo $v.'<br/>';

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y que es lo que hace este codigo?

Comment: Busca el dato que necesito y lo pinta en pantalla, `scraping`, pero no me sirve con PHP. @IvanIsayenko, sabes de alguna forma de hacerlo ?

Comment: No vas a poder porque existe un problema de CORS. Auqnue puedes poner el código PHP en un fichero en un servidor cualquiera (controlado por ti y sin CORS) y usar el método .load de jQuery para cargarlo desde javascript.

Comment: Pero por que me lo muestra de esta forma entonces?como lo puedo hacer? lo que me dices arriba? @track3r

Comment: CORS afecta al lado del cliente pero no al servidor.

Comment: Para hacer lo que digo arriba, simplemente pon ese PHP que nos muestras en un servidor, por ejemplo: tuserver.com/scraping.php y luego en un html haz: $("body").load("tuserver.com/scraping.php"); o cambia body por el selector en dónde quieras ponerlo, puede ser un div oculto y luego lo trabajas normal con jquery.

Comment: No me queda claro una cosa, quieres sacar estos datos en Cliente o en Servidor? porque son dos cosas diferentes

Comment: En servidor, no especifiqué bien lo siento. @IvanIsayenko

Comment: Okey, si es servidor entiendo que utilizas NodeJS verdad? o usas PHP?

Comment: Utilizo Node JS

Comment: Entonces faltaria complementar tu pregunta con codigo de NodeJS(lo que tienes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer con nodejs, puedes usar esto para obtener la página:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data); // Aquí el parser
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Y luego puedes usar cheerio para realizar el parseo correspondiente: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Sería algo así:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(data);

trm = $.find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");
```

No lo puedo probar porque no tengo el entorno preparado, pero la parte del get la he probado online en https://repl.it/repls/DisastrousOlivedrabAbstracttype y funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

con JS o AngularJS podrías intentar hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var valores = [];

valores.push(document.querySelector(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").querySelector(".item-value > span").innerHTML);

//querySelector por defecto te devuelve la primera coincidencia
//querySelectors te devolverá TODAS las coincidencia en una `array`, tendrás que indicar la posición que quieres (document.querySelectors(".item-row[data-item='TRM']")[0])
```

Es bastante fácil, después de coger todos los datos que quieres, puedes manipular la `array` y hacer lo que necesites!

Comment: Pero debo incluir esta parte? `include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");` para que me funcione.

Comment: Te he votado negativo porque el problema real, que no queda claro en la pregunta, es que no puede cargar la dirección desde html ya que existe un problema de CORS.

Comment: Yo lo que entiendo es que no tiene acceso directo al DOM, se tendría que imprimir la respuesta que obtiene y después realizar mi código.